# Create tag [jpms] even though it is similar to [jpm]

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-creation-request

When trying to create the [jpms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jpms) tag, a helpful SCREAMING RED ERROR BOX told me:

> You are attempting to create the tag [jpms]; however the tag [jpm] already exists! If you think this new tag should be allowed, raise it on meta

So here I am.

JPMS is the abbreviation the JDK team uses to describe the *Java Platform Module System*, a new addition in Java 9 that will cause a lot of trouble and hence hundreds of questions. Looking over the the first page of [java-9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-9), about half of them would carry the new tag.

JPMS is an obvious choice because (a) the JDK team uses it and (b) Java Module System would lead to JMS, which is already taken. But apart from that, something weirder like [java-modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-modules) would also be acceptable (for me).

Comment: why not `java-jpms` ?

Comment: Personally, I find self repeating acronyms ridiculous: `java-jpms` = `java-java-platform-module-system`. But if that's the only way out...

Comment: Yes but don't forget the tag criteria : a tag must be not ambiguous, having jpm/jpms could be interpreted as "s" for secure like http/https when it's not.

Comment: I'd suggest `java-pms` but this might not be the right time. :)

Comment: What is the decision on this? What do we use? (FWIW, I agree with `jpms`, given that `jdbc`, `jms`, and `jpa` already establish using official Java names)

Comment: Just tried to create this tag myself as I needed it. JPMS is the official abbreviation so why can't we use it?

Comment: I totally agree that `jpms` should be a tag. The tag [tag:java-module] does exist but only covers a part of the JPMS. The tag [tag:jigsaw] exists as well which might be seen as synonym of the possible tag `jpms` as it kind of covers the same thing (but actually describes the project leading to the JPMS).

Answer (score 1):

No, we already have such a tag. It is called [java-platform-module-system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-platform-module-system).

Furthermore [jpms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jpms) is already [a synonym of [java-platform-module-system] and [java-module] is currently voted on to be synonymized](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-platform-module-system/synonyms).

[image: box appearing when trying to ask a question with [jpms]]